# AutoMapper, Don't Overwrite Existing Value if Not Present

Tags: c#, automapper

I have two models that are similar but not exactly the same

```
public class ResponseModel
{
    public int? AccountId { get; set; }
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public string AccountLegalname { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Information
{
    public int? IdentityId { get; set; }
    public int? AccountId { get; set; }
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public string AccountLegalName { get; set; }
}
```

And I am trying to combine these two models like so

```
var test1 = new Information(){
    IdentityId = 1234
};

var test2 = new ResponseModel()
{
    AccountId = 123214,
    AccountLegalname = "test",
    AccountNumber = "9239235",
    Link = "link"
};

test1 = _mapper.Map<ResponseModel, Information>(test2);
```

What I want is this to result in test1 combining the two models values to populate one full instance of `Information`.

But what actually happens is that all of the information from test2 is inserted into test1 and `test1.IdentityId = null`

I tried this,

```
this.CreateMap<ResponseModel, Information>()
    .ForAllMembers(o => o.Condition((source, destination, member) => member != null));
```

But no luck.

How can I make it so test2 does not override data that exists int test1 and not in test2?

Comment: I remember doing something like this at one point and had to set conditionals for each member.

Comment: I think Obeds answer in the bottom works: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12262940/usedestinationvalue-only-when-destination-property-is-not-null

Comment: The problem here is not that you're overwriting the properties, the problem is that the overload you used constructed a new target object, the instance in `test1` was never used, instead you overwrote `test1` with this new instance, losing the original one where you had assigned to that Id property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am not mistaken you can pass the destination as argument to call that specific functionality through the overload:

```
test1 = _mapper.Map(test2, test1 );
```

Comment: And I think you can get away too without the types, they are inferred from the params.

Comment: Yes this is it.  Well played

Comment: Makes me wonder what it will do with value types though, like `int`s.